# Is there a way to make an iterator variable greater than something and less then something?

Tags: javascript

So, the assignment is generating a random password between 7-10 characters. Is this valid syntax in my for loop which generates the amount of numbers.

```js
var password = "";
var characters =
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@#$";
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var char = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length + 1);
  password += characters.charAt(char);
}
console.log(password);
```

So, this current for loop makes the password ten characters.
I want it to be between 7 and 10 characters.
Is it valid Javascript syntax to do i<=10 && i>=7?

Comment: It's valid syntax but it won't produce the result you want because `i=1` doesn't fulfill the condition and thus the loop body is never executed. There are multiple ways to do what you want. The simplest might be to choose a random number between 7 and 10 and use that in your stop condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is select a random number from 0 to 3. Based on that number, you will decide how long your password is. Could be `7+0` or `7+1` or `7+2` or `7+3`.

Now the number of times your loop runs is dynamic and hence you will get passwords of different lengths.

```js
var password = "";
var characters =
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@#$";

let x = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
for (i = 1; i <= (7+x); i++) {
  var char = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length + 1);
  password += characters.charAt(char);
}
console.log(password);
```

Comment: Note that `x` will never be `3` so the maximum length of the password will be `9`.  I guess you need `Math.random() * 4`.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks